# XML invalid Character !.

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have been getting an invalid character! on what looks like the £ sign in the xml i am processing. I get "Invalid character in the given encoding." here is a code & xml snippet.

```
<outputs>
<output id='1'>
<key><![CDATA[123]]></key>
<message id='84'>
<source><![CDATA[123]]></source>
<sender><![CDATA[Paul]]></sender>
<text><![CDATA[Testing Currency £7.50 $9.999 _]]></text>
</message>
</output>
</outputs>
```

Not much I am doing code wise.

```
       XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName);
```

I don't alter the encoding or anything. Any tips ?.

Comment: What is the encoding of the XML? Is it different than UTF-8? If yes, do you have an XML declaration at the start specifying the encoding?

Comment: The last time I had this it was because the Xml Declaration claimed it was UTF-8 but the file had been saved as ANSI - hence the special characters were not encoded correctly. You can quickly test this by opening in Notepad, then, in the Save As dialog, you can change the Encoding to UTF-8 in the Encoding drop down. With the file now encoded as UTF-8 for sure, try reopening it in your code.

Comment: I think processing instruction is the term http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The £ sign has ASCII value 163 (0xA3) and UTF-8 codes 0xC2 0xA3 ([source](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm)).

Make sure the file encoding (which seems to be ASCII) matches the encoding used for loading the XML file using a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) with Encoding parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you load an XML document, you might get this encoding problem:

**An invalid character was found in text content.**

You get this error if your XML contains non ASCII characters, and the file was saved as single-byte ANSI (or ASCII) with no encoding specified.

**Windows Notepad** saves files as single-byte ANSI (ASCII) by default.

To fix your problem, you can open your xml using **NotePad**, then if you select "Save as...", you can specify single-byte Unicode (UTF-8), then try to reload your XML.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why you got this error.

I have copied your XML in POC.XML file and modified the build properties of this file to copy always. after that below code worked without exception.

```
XDocument xodc = XDocument.Load("poc.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

add xml header to your file in order to specify the encoding method < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>